# Duplicated paths in windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line

I don't know what did I do but suddenly when I ran windows command line I saw duplicated paths
 `C:\WINDOWS\system32>C:\WINDOWS\system32>`

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something has changed your `PROMPT` environment variable to `$P$G$P$G`.

Simple fix is to write `SET PROMPT=$P$G`. But the change may have been applied more resiliently than just the current command prompt - you may have to edit your `Environment Variables` settings.

Comment: I did but no changes! The windows powershell works fine but when I run windows command line I see what I mentioned.